# Application defined error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to  compare 2 cell values and further logic is based on the values in both the cells.

My code is giving "Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined Error".

Below is the part where I am getting the issue

```
Pass = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("i20:i256"), "P")
Fail = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("j20:j256"), "F")

Temp1 = (Pass + Fail)

For num = 20 To 256
If Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("i(num)").Value = "P" And _
 Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("j(num)").Value = "F" Then

    MsgBox ("Both column cannot contain values")

End If
Next num
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
If Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("i(num)").Value = "P" And Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("j(num)").Value = "F" Then
```

by this line:

```
If Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("I" & num).Value = "P" And Worksheets("QA Checklist Banners").Range("J" & num).Value = "F" Then
```

Comment: Thank you for the help......After lot of research I finally made it I modified the code as If Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(num, 9) = "P" And Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(num, 10) = "F" Then

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the output as required by modifying my code

```
For Num = 20 To 256
   If Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(Num, 9) = "P" And Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(Num, 10) = "F" Then
    Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(Num, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Sheets("QA Checklist Banners").Cells(Num, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    MsgBox ("Both column cannot contain values")
    End If
Next Num
```